# Setting JLabel text programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So I'm trying to make the JLabel work in this code. I can get the button and Action Listener to work but not the Label.
MyDice is where I create the Panels and buttons.

```
public class MyDice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyDice v1.0");
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setLocation(560, 240);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(200,200,200));
        panel.setSize(800,600);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        JButton button_d4    = new JButton("Roll d4");
        panel.add(button_d4);
        button_d4.addActionListener   (new MyRoll(4,panel));
    }
}
```

And the MyRoll is where I got the Action Listener that does something when I click the buttons.

```
public class MyRoll implements ActionListener
{
    int dice;
    JPanel panel;

    public MyRoll (int dice, JPanel panel)
    {
        this.dice = dice;
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        rollDice(dice,1);
    }

    public void rollDice (int dice, int times)
    {
        int r=0;
        for (int i=0; i<times;i++)
        {
            double rand = Math.random();
            rand = rand*dice + 1;
            r = (int) rand;
        }

            System.out.println("You rolled "+r+" out of "+dice);

        JLabel output = new JLabel();
        output.setText("You rolled "+r+" out of "+dice);
        panel.add(output);

    }
}
```

However, this last part does not work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  a JLabel and set the Label Message in your logic

**REVISION for the updated CODE POSTED**

You should set up the Label outside of the Logic, added to the Panel with initial empty value and then on your logic you change the Label's Value

i.e

```
//Setting up your GUI
JLabel label = new JLabel("");
panel.add(label);


//Within your Logic method
System.out.println("Printing info");
label.setLabel("Printing info");
```

That way you are not constantly adding a JLabel to your Panel

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick answer. I did try to use the JLabel but it just wouldn't show up. Any reason for that?

Comment: Maybe the Panel is not being refreshed?

Comment: Hence my question about the existence of a Panel.refresh().
I really don't know why it wouldn't show.

Comment: Have you added the JLabel to the JPanel?

Comment: Yes, I showed in the first post the actual code. If you can, please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following code:

```
    JLabel output = new JLabel(); 
    output.setText("You rolled "+r+" out of "+dice); 
    panel.add(output);
```

Here you are adding a new `JLabel` to the panel (which happens to be in your main frame) every time you click the button. However, you there is nothing to tell it to repaint itself.

My suggestion to fix this is to create the `JLabel` and add it to the `JPanel` in `main()` and pass the JLabel reference to your `MyRoll` class. Then you can simply call `setText()` any time you wish. You really don't need a reference to the `JPanel` in `MyRoll`; you just need a reference to the `JLabel`.

**p.s.** I want to make a few comments on your `main()` method. In particular, if you organize your code differently, you can simplify it a little bit. Typically creating a Swing GUI follows these steps:

1. Create a `JFrame`.
2. Create a `JPanel`.
3. Add components to the `JPanel`.
4. Add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.
5. Set the `JFrame` visible.

Notice that you only need to call `setVisible()` on the `JFrame`, if you do it very last. This will automatically call `setVisible()` on the `JPanel` and all its subcomponents.

Comment: As I replied above, I couldn't get this to work. I made the class MyRoll (the one I call with the JButton) with 2 arguments:
    int dice
    JPanel panel

Passing my panel like this, should it work?

Comment: @LaísMinchillo Please post the code where you tried to use a JLabel. We need more details to diagnose why it didn't work.

Comment: @LaísMinchillo Also, I added an alternative solution.

Comment: Edit: put it in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a refresh method, there is none that I know of for .
Instead you can set up a thread, that updates the output depending on the logic you provide.

Comment: But how do I update the output? There must be some sort of function?